# Twitter v2 API search endpoint "Field Authorization Error"

Tags: node.js, twitter

When requesting 'organic_metrics' field in Twitter v2 API search endpoint I am getting the following: "Field Authorization Error"

This is my request script in Nodejs

```
function requestSearch (keyword) {

    const search = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent',
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "v2RecentSearchJS",
            "authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
        },
        qs: {
            query: "context:66.1001503516555337728 context:66.857879456773357569" // `entity: ${keyword}`
        },
        json: true,
        gzip: true
    };

    const params = {
        "ids": "1397885797957738496", // Edit Tweet IDs to look up
        "tweet.fields": "context_annotations,entities,organic_metrics", // Edit optional query parameters here
        "user.fields": "created_at" // Edit optional query parameters here,
    }
    const lookup = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets',
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "v2RecentSearchJS",
            "authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN}`
        },
        qs: params
    }
    return rp(lookup)
        .then(response => {
            // console.log('API call response:', response);
            return response
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('API call error:', err.message);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics):

> Public metrics can be requested with OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token authentication. Non-public metrics can be requested for owned/authorized Tweets only. This means developers are required to authenticate using OAuth 1.0a User Context authorization. If you need to generate an access token and secret for the Tweet owner, you can do so with the 3-legged OAuth process.

[...]

> **Organic metrics:** Grouping of public and non-public metrics attributed to an organic context (posted and viewed in a regular manner). Requires OAuth 1.0a User Context authentication.

In this case, you are using a Bearer Token to access the API, so you will not be able to access the organic metrics (this is what the "Field Authorization Error" message is telling you). You could use the `public_metrics` field instead.