# Is there any way to retrieve your own tweet organic_metrics and at the same time the referenced_tweets without theirs Twiter API V2

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2, node-twitter

I am trying to request my own timeline tweets `organic_metrics` by adding them on the `tweet.fields`. By doing so, I retrieve them as expected.

The problem is that if I add the `expansions` `referenced_tweets.id,referenced_tweets.id.author_id`  to the query I get a Field Authorization Error because (I presume) its attempting to retrieve the `organic_metrics` from the referenced tweets.

Here is an error example:

```
  {
    "resource_type": "tweet",
    "field": "organic_metrics.like_count",
    "parameter": "referenced_tweets.id",
    "resource_id": "1602665220689764353",
    "title": "Field Authorization Error",
    "section": "includes",
    "detail": "Sorry, you are not authorized to access 'organic_metrics.like_count' on the Tweet with referenced_tweets.id : [1602665220689764353].",
    "value": "1602665220689764353",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/not-authorized-for-field"
  },
```

With this error the `referenced_tweets` do not come in the response and therefore I am unable to retrieve my own tweets `organic_metrics` and the `referenced_tweets` in the same response.
I am forced to do x2 queries

I understand I can not access the `organic_metrics` on the `referenced_tweets` and I don't want to, I just need my own `organic_metrics`.

Is there any way to tell the API that I just want the `organic_metrics` of my tweets while at the same time retrieve the `referenced_tweets` without `organic_metrics`?

Comment: if not paid account, you can't access `organic_metrics` even if your own tweet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732581/twitter-v2-api-search-endpoint-field-authorization-error

Comment: Thanks for answering @BenchVue. Actually I have already authenticate using OAuth 1.0a User Context authorization so I am able to retrieve the organic ones. What I am not able is to retrieve the organic and the referenced tweets at the same time